# Finding the number of Channels from an AVAsset

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, core-audio

I am loading Audio assets via AVAssets.  I want to figure out how many channels (mono or stereo basically) are in the asset.  What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This appears to be what I am looking for.

```
AVAssetTrack* songTrack = [mAssetToLoad.tracks objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray* formatDesc = songTrack.formatDescriptions;
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < [formatDesc count]; ++i) {
    CMAudioFormatDescriptionRef item = (CMAudioFormatDescriptionRef)[formatDesc objectAtIndex:i];
    const AudioStreamBasicDescription* bobTheDesc = CMAudioFormatDescriptionGetStreamBasicDescription (item);
    if(bobTheDesc && bobTheDesc->mChannelsPerFrame == 1) {
        mIsMono = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 implementation of TurqMage's answer

```
//
//  AVAssetTrack+IsStereo.swift
//

import AVFoundation

extension AVAssetTrack {
    
    var isStereo: Bool {
        
        for item in (formatDescriptions as? [CMAudioFormatDescription]) ?? [] {
            
            let basic = CMAudioFormatDescriptionGetStreamBasicDescription(item)
            let numberOfChannels = basic?.pointee.mChannelsPerFrame ?? 0
            
            if numberOfChannels == 2 {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```